# Clear static variables in another library C++

Tags: c++, static

I have a program written in C++ which calls a function in another library. I'm able to get the correct answer from the library the first time i call a given function.
However, the call fails the second time. I think this function use some kind of static variables, which are set to a default value before the first call. During the first call the static variable is changed, so that the second call fails. (I'm able to reset some static variable but probably not all.)

Are there any ways to reset all static variables in C++ to their default value?

Comment: Please show relevant code!

Comment: No, there is no way, unless you catch up all of them and reset manually.

Comment: If there is static variables to initialize, I suppose there is a function to get the library in a initialized state...Maybe you have to call something prior of the specific function. Otherwise the only way to reset is to restart the program.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using this library in a way it is not designed for, that's way there are no initialization call. So it seems like I need to file a bug report/feature request.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's usually unproductive to say that something is impossible. Most goals are attainable at *some* cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load library using `dlopen` function, use the functions, and then use `dlclose`. After that a library is unloaded and all it's data is (hopefully) cleared.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html

Update: `dlopen` works with shared libraries. If you have a static library, you can wrap it into shared.

The path to the loaded library can be absolute, relative, or without a path component, in which case default ld.so mechanism is used (LD_LIBARY_PATH, /lib, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In POSIX, the first string in the `argv` parameter to `main` is a path representing the UNIX executable that was invoked. You can replace the current process with a new executable by calling `execvp` (or [something similar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)).

It follows that you can reset the state of global variables by calling `execvp`.

Note, however, that resetting all the global variables will also reset the state of the heap, so all objects allocated with `malloc` or `new` will no longer exist. Also, execution will be reset to `main` so objects on the stack will be lost too.

It would fundamentally be unsafe to hack the state of a library, so the language does not allow you to do so.

[Here's a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1b7842c29503be1). Note that it expects you to pass an initial command-line argument of `0`, for the sake of terminating itself. Termination might not be an issue in your program, and there are other ways to solve the problem. Ask another question if necessary.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

void f() {
    static int cnt = 0;

    std::cout << cnt ++ << '\n';
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    f();
    f();

    if ( * argv[1] == '0' ) {
        ++ * argv[1];
        std::cout << "try again" << std::endl;

        execvp( argv[0], argv );
    }
    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```

output:

```
0
1
try again
0
1
done
```